# Algorithm or formula for computing elapsed time at any given distance in a dataset?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, statistics

I have one dataset that includes distance markers (m).

**Sorted Distance Markers**

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "distance": 0
    },
    {
      "distance": 500
    },
    {
      "distance": 1100
    },
    {
      "distance": 1300
    },
    {
      "distance": 2000
    },...
  ]
}
```

And many sorted cumulative datasets that include traversed distance (m) and elapsed time (s). Distance and time always initiate at 0m and 0s.

**Variable Dataset Object 1**

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "distance": 0,
      "time": 0
    },
    {
      "distance": 230,
      "time": 34.23
    },
    {
      "distance": 450,
      "time": 95.21
    },
    {
      "distance": 1150,
      "time": 180.31
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to know what is the most efficient way for finding the elapsed time at every marker distance ***d*** for Object 1. One way could be finding the average from the two dataset records closest to distance ***d***. Or via a chart formula?

Thanks

Comment: Not at all clear from your description: is Object 1 showing a bunch of independent distances and times, or is it showing cumulative distances and times where it took 34.23s to go the first 230m, then (95.21 - 34.23) to go the next (450 - 230)m, etc.?  Is there any other info to explain why the speed might vary, such as acceleration/deceleration occurring over the elapsed time?  I don't think there's enough info for anybody to give you meaningful recommendations.

Comment: Hi @pjs The information has been rephrased for clarification. The data is sorted. And regarding Object 1 that is right. The distance and time are cumulative. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the use of linear regression, although one reference point (0, 0) and three observations is pretty sparse unless you have some conceptual basis for the structure of your regression model.  Nevertheless, regressing `distance` on `time` for Object 1 while forcing the model through the intercept yields a pretty good fit:

> d = 6.037t

[image: Data Plot w/ Regression Line]

[image: Regression Fit]

R<sup>2</sup> can't be estimated due to forcing the curve through origin, and there aren't enough points to get a reliable estimate of whether curvature might be involved.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Using binary search on the variable dataset (which is already sorted) to find the distance ***d*** or closest distances (insertion point). O(log n)

If ***d*** exists in variable data set, the elapsed time can be returned immediately. Otherwise it can be computed from the closest distances (insertion point) via an average formula that takes into account the closeness of lower and upper bound to ***d***.  O(1)